# Can pam_mount be called from sudo env?

Tags: mount, automount, pam

I'm building a compute cluster of Linux nodes (all Ubuntu 16, upgraded today!), so many users will effectively login to each node, and I want various network shares to exist without them having to write explicit mount commands in their scripts, which would need their passwords.

SO. I've got `pam_mount` working; it automatically mounts their home drive (everyone has one), then picks up their personal `.pam_mount_config.xml` from that home drive, and mounts anything else they want. This works perfectly if they SSH to a node.

However, the way a compute node runs a job is by doing this from a daemon on the compute node: (my username is `wes`, the folder is already auto-generated)

```
sudo -E -u wes env "PATH=$PATH" /bin/bash /tmp/nodemanager_task_109_0.dKLE3e/run_dir_in_out.sh
```

The problem is the login with `sudo env` does not call any of the PAM scripts that mount any shares. I have no control over this command, although I effectively have control over what gets called in `run_dir_in_out.sh`, as that runs the script for my cluster job.

Is there a way of getting it to mount the shares in exactly the same way as it would if user `wes` had `ssh`-ed in, either by any clever configuration, or by manually making the `pam_mount` process happen?

Sorry for the wordy question - any assistance really appreciated.

Comment: Make the session an `ssh` session and automate the modifications to be made on the `xml` file afterwards..all can be incorporated in the script..

Comment: Not sure I understand - I can't change the sudo line - that is run by the compute cluster software to run the job using my username, thus getting access to all the network shares that my username can access. I somehow need sudo -E -u wes env to do the same mounting process on a node, as it would do if I ssh-ed to that same node.

Comment: First of all, the `env PATH="$PATH"` is redundant here, you are already preserving the environment with `-E`. Now what i meant is that you can change the script to accommodate the commands that are needed to do what you want i.e. run ssh and modify the xml file and so on.

Comment: Yes, I know about the PATH bit being redundant- but what I'm saying is: I cannot change that - it comes from inside the cluster management software, which is basically a closed box that I just have to deal with. I won't need to edit the XML - I just need to get the user's home drive mounted and have PAM read that file as it is. So are you saying it's possible to run a completely non-interactive ssh session, with the "current" user/password, and send more commands to it, all from a bash script?

Comment: That would be perfect... where do I start?! Can't find anything close to that in my googling so far - I've only read pages that say ssh is a problem for this because it requires manual keyboard input etc... I'd have to do it in a totally scripted way without human intervention...

Comment: Here is a start: test this on your computer: `ssh localhost 'whoami; echo foobar; echo spam; whoami` ..got the idea? If not, post the content you want to automate, i would have a look..If the input is being read from terminal we need `expect`, if from STDIN its far easy..

Comment: No, echo doesn't feed the text to ssh - "expect" would be the way, but the problem with these methods is that the users' password would have to be in plain text on the job submission entry, which is publically viewable.The sudo env script gets them onto the node that is going to do the work for them without needing them to give their password again (the cluster manager knows their password and caches it, so it can do that login)... they just need their home drive mounted so they can access their actual files!